# Calculating Eigenvalue and Eigenvector for 3x3 matrix with Accord.NET

Tags: c#, eigenvalue, eigenvector, accord.net, matrix-decomposition

I wanted to get the eigenvectors and eigenvalues out of a 3x3 matrix.

I've already tried to use the `EigenvalueDecomposition` from Accord.
The problem(?) I have with the resulting eigenvectors is that online calculators for eigenvectors are giving me different vectors from what Accord.NET does.

More precisely, I tried Accord's `EigenvalueDecomposition` on this test matrix:

> (1, 2, 3)
>
> (4, 5, 6)
>
> (7, 8, 9)

where the `arndt-bruenner` calculator (http://www.arndt-bruenner.de/mathe/scripts/engl_eigenwert2.htm) gives me these results:

> Real Eigenvalues:   { -1.1168439698070431 ;  0 ;  16.116843969807043 }
>
> Eigenvectors:
>
> for Eigenvalue -1.1168439698070431:
>
> [ -0.785830238742067 ; -0.08675133925662847 ; 0.6123275602288102 ]
>
> for Eigenvalue 0:
>
> [ 0.4082482904638631 ; -0.8164965809277261 ; 0.4082482904638631 ]
>
> for Eigenvalue 16.116843969807043:
>
> [ 0.2319706872462859 ; 0.5253220933012337 ; 0.8186734993561815 ]

Now when I use this test matrix on Accords EigenvalueDecomposition, I get these results:

> (0.231970687246286, 0.816964204061037, 0.408248290463863)
>
> (0.525322093301234, 0.0901883579085377, -0.816496580927726)
>
> (0.818673499356182, -0.636587488243964, 0.408248290463863)

The eigenvalues however are correct with the results from the online calculator.

What am I doing wrong and how do I have to use Accord's functions correctly for this?

I only did this in c#:

```
double[,] kovarianzmatrix = new double[,]
        {
            {1, 2, 3},
            {4, 5, 6},
            {7, 8, 9}
        };

        Accord.Math.Decompositions.EigenvalueDecomposition solver = new Accord.Math.Decompositions.EigenvalueDecomposition(kovarianzmatrix, false, true);
```

And printed the eigenvectors in the console.